# How to set available options for Comment Per Page select?

Tags: comments

In Drupal 7, In comment setting a option **Comments per page** show 10, 30, 50, 70, 90, ... 300. I want to option "Comment per page" show like 1, 2, 3, 4, .... .

[image]

Comment: It's kind of a duplicate, however it doesn't show how to change the options, just how to change the default selection so I'm not sure it's fully a duplicate.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan Both answers there **do not answer** this question. I would leave this open and reword older one to make sure it is consistent with interpretation shown by both answerers. What do you all think?

Answer (score 0):

Comments per page options are taken from [`_comment_per_page` function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/_comment_per_page/7) and as you can see, are hardcoded:

```
function _comment_per_page() {
  return drupal_map_assoc(array(10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 150, 200, 250, 300));
}
```

To substitute this with your own function, you need to implement [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), and override changes made by [`comment_form_node_type_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_form_node_type_form_alter/7). Specifically, you need to change `$form['comment']['comment_default_per_page']['#options']` and make sure `$form['comment']['comment_default_per_page']['#default_value']` makes sense after that change.

To make sure your hook fires after the one by comment module, see [Can I change the order in which hook implementation by different modules are called?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/404/16495)